# How to create a rowspan of rows from an array?

Tags: spring, thymeleaf

I want to merge the lines that have data in common but differ in one column. My project is about incident management. Each incident may have 1 to many criteria impacted so the result of the chart looks like this:

```
num | incident | criteria impacted
----+----------+--------------------------------
1   | Major    | disponibility
1   | Major    | confidentiality
```

But I would like the result to look like this:

```
num | incident | criteria impacted
----+----------+--------------------------------
1   | Major    | disponibility , confidentiality
```

My thymeleaf code looks like this:

```
    <td>N°</td><td>Incident</td><td>Critére impacté</td>
</tr>
<tr th:each="t:${criticite}" align="center">
    <td th:text="${t.incident.id}"></td>
    <td th:text="${t.incident.class.simpleName}"></td>
    <td th:text="${t.class.simpleName}"></td>
</tr>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you planning to change the Java beans to reflect this change, or do you want to just show it on the Thymeleaf page this way?  For example, is `criteria impacted` now a `java.util.List` or still a `String`?  You may be better off doing the merge on the server-side to keep things cleaner and testable.

Comment: rather I am looking for a thymeleaf action that removes the repetition of lines that have the same data I used th: rowspan but it's not working

Comment: My controller @RequestMapping(value="/consulterIncident",method=RequestMethod.GET)
 public String consulterInc(Model model){
  
  
  model.addAttribute("incident",cr.findAll());
  return "ListeIncident";
 }                                                                                                                                 thank's for your answer